# able to remove GroupMembershipInfo from ContactEntry, but unable to add GroupMembershipInfo

Tags: java, gdata-api, google-data-api

**What is the proper way to update an existing ContactEntry to include GroupMembershipInfo in an existing ContactGroupEntry?**

I am using the Java APIs com.google.gdata.data.contacts...

```
// groupNameId was fetched with ContactGroupEntry.getId()
// entry is a known-good ContactEntry
// contactsService is a properly authenticated feed

GroupMembershipInfo g = new GroupMembershipInfo();
g.setHref(groupNameId);
entry.addGroupMembershipInfo(g); 
contactsService.update(new URL(entry.getEditLink().getHref()), entry);
// .... fails with PreconditionFailedException
```

*I am able to successfully retrieve contacts and remove group membership, but adding group membership is eluding me, and I have been unable to figure out the right Google search to find a useful piece of sample code*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*GroupEntry is added to the GroupMembership which is added to the ContactEntry*

**entry.getGroupMembershipInfos().add(g);**

```
GroupMembershipInfo g = new GroupMembershipInfo();
g.setHref(groupNameId);
entry.getGroupMembershipInfos().add(g);
contactsService.update(new URL(entry.getEditLink().getHref()), entry);
```